# How small is $x$ when $x\ll{1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

When $x\ll{1}$, then how close to zero is $x$. I mean what value of $x$ makes $x\ll{1}$. Are the values $x = 0.5,\; 0.001, \;0.00001$ OK?

I am solving a complicated equation that contains the variables $x$ and $y$, and I know that $x\ll{1}$ and $y$ is about $10^{-9}$. The equation can be written in two different forms when $x<y$ and when $x>y$. Is it right to assume that $x<y$?

Comment: There is no rule. Just fine $0.1$, $0.000001$ etc.

Comment: The exact answer lies in the kind of approximation you are using. For example if it is some kind of linearization, [Lagrange's remainder][1] gives you an estimate of the error, hence a bound on the largeness of $x$.[1]: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html

Answer (score 3):

The entire point of saying $x \ll 1 $ is that it is NOT clear exactly what you mean. How small $x$ is will affect how accurate your approximation is. For instance, if $x=0$, your approximation will usually not be an approximation.

What people mean when they say when $x \ll 1$, $f(x) \approx g(x)$, that means that there is some error term that can be controlled in a nice way.

By saying "small", you are being vague and that's the point.

Edit: To push the issue a little further, $x$ is "small enough" if whatever approximation you are using is "good enough". Now what does "good enough" mean? Again, this is intentionally vague. The point isn't precisely how small $x$ is or how "good" the error is, it's that the error can be controlled in a manageable way.